# "when others" line in VHDL case statement?

Tags: vhdl

I'm a student learning VHDL and the example code from my textbook shows lines similar to the following in several places;

```
when "000" => tmp_result <= a and b;
when "001" => tmp_result <= a or b;
...
when others => tmp_result <= (others => '0');
```

I find the syntax of VHDL very unintuitive overall, but I really don't "get" this line at all.

I'm really confused why the above line isn't just:

```
when others => tmp_result <= '0'
```

Why is it like that?

I've tried Googling but haven't been able to find an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` has a fixed size. So, when you are assigning a value to it, instead of defining each bit explicitly, you can just use

```
(others => '0')
```

to denote you want the remaining bits to be set to `0`. Since the variable has a fixed size, your compiler will know how many bits to set. You could mix this with a bunch of other statements, e.g.

```
tmp_result <= (1=>'1', OTHERS => '0');
```

A circumstance where it could come in handy is this:

```
ENTITY test IS
    GENERIC (n : INTEGER := 7);
    PORT (a : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n DOWNTO 0)
          );
END test;
```

You see, we may have to change the size each time and that's why we are defining a `generic` variable. Using `(others => '0')` to set it to `0` will save us from having to change the whole program all over again.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `tmp_result` is defined as *std_logic_vector* (instead of simply *std_logic*).

```
tmp_result <= '0';             -- tmp_result is std_logic (single-quotes)
tmp_result <= "0000000";       -- tmp_result is std_logic_vector (double quotes)
tmp_result <= (others => '0'); -- same as previous line, but does not need to know length of tmp_result
```

When assigning all the bits of a *std_logic_vector* to the same value (`'0'`, in this case), it is common practice to use the syntax `(others => '0')`, which basically translate to "give me a std_logic_vector the same length as tmp_result filled with '0'". This is better because the line is still valid when the length of `tmp_result` changes, such as if its length depends on a generic.